# Is it correct for using a single interceptor as default-interceptor-ref in struts?

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor, struts2-interceptors

This is the interceptor definition my `struts.xml`, but this may be incorrect, because IDE prompts me the error **Cannot resolve interceptor-stack `login`** at **default-interceptor-ref**

If I ignore this error to deploy to server, this interceptor still works fine.

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="login" class="com.pos.interceptor.LoginInterceptor"></interceptor>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="login"/>
    <global-results>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="login" type="redirect">/login.jsp</result>
    </global-results>


    <action name="profile" class="com.pos.UserProfile" method="index">
        <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

If I define a interceptor stack, the IDE will be no error

```
        <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="login"/>
        </interceptor-stack>
    <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
```

Both of above are work after deploy. Is it correct if I use single interceptor as default interceptor?

If it is correct, why IDE prompts the error? Can I solve the error?

If it is incorrect, why it will work after deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All classes live in application context, Struts object factory creates instances of classes and returns them when they are referenced.

default stack is overridden by you when you specify it. So default Stack is unavailable for the actions in that package.

### Part 1: When you specify interceptor-ref name= login

When you specify somestring in name attribute, it parses that string then it gets object from [StrutsObjectFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.1/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ObjectFactory.java?av=f) then it creates its list in memory. Then [InterceptorBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.1/com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/providers/InterceptorBuilder.java?av=f) class creates list of references. This class returns list of mappings.

### Part 2: When you write default-interceptor-ref

**Why XML showing error?**

`<default-interceptor-ref >` is used to define default stack of interceptors, xml is showing error because you are specifying interceptor instead of interceptor-stack. As per DTD it is invalid. As per DTD it is expecting a type of interceptor-stack.

**How to remove XML error?**

You can disable xml check to remove that error, or can specify valid configuration by creating stack and specifying stack to it, as you showed in second part.

**Why it is working with single interceptor ref also?**

It is working because the implementation accepts single interceptor reference also. Actually that configuration is passing the reference. So if you pass stack, it will have reference to collection, if you are passing single interceptor, it will pass the reference of the single interceptor only.

Now in struts2 there is source code available on internet.

[InterceptorStackConfig](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.1/com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/entities/InterceptorStackConfig.java?av=f) is the class that builds list and uses [InterceptorlistHolder](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.16.3/com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/entities/InterceptorListHolder.java#InterceptorListHolder) interface. [InterceptorStackConfig](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork-core/2.1.4/com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/entities/InterceptorStackConfig.java) implements this interface in builder and adds interceptors mapping references from interceptor mappings one by one to list.

> It means that it deals only with [mapping](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.1/com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/entities/InterceptorMapping.java#InterceptorMapping) and get reference.

You can see it has [InterceptorListHolder](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.16.3/com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/entities/InterceptorListHolder.java#InterceptorListHolder) interface which creates list of interceptors for your stacks, it accepts both **single interceptor mapping** and **list of interceptor mappings** for adding interceptor mappping to list.

```
 InterceptorListHolder  addInterceptor(InterceptorMapping interceptor);
 InterceptorListHolder  addInterceptors(List<InterceptorMapping> interceptors);
```

So it is working when you specify only one interceptor because of its dealing with reference.

But still I will suggest you to use *dafaultStack* also with combination of login interceptor to make your application fully working.